# Finding position of match with zero-width assertions

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a script that will find an open reading frame of a DNA sequence. However, I need to make sure that the regex can find overlapping regions, and thus used a lookahead assertion. The problem is that when I am trying to show the position of the match, python is not returning the expected values. I suspect that this is because ?= is a zero-width assertion. How should I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is matching a zero-length string immediately prior to the `ATG`. You should then capture a single group, but a group that does not contribute to your match, so you probably get a `-1` for your `match.start` and `match.end`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end

finditer() is specifically for non-overlapping matches, so you're going to have to decide between using finditer() versus start() and end(). See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer

I don't know enough to recommend an elegant replacement for finditer().

Answer (score 0):

Take the good group....

I hope I've guessed correctly what you want.

```
import re

def orfs(sequence, aa):
     rframe = []
     orf_re = ('(?='
               '('
               'ATG(?:[ATGC]{3}){%d,}?'
               '(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)'
               ')'
               ')' \
                % (aa))
     for match in re.finditer(orf_re, sequence):
         print 'groups()',repr(match.groups()),match.span()
         print 'group(0)',repr(match.group(0)),match.span(0)
         print 'group(1)',repr(match.group(1)),match.span(1)
         print
         rframe.append('span (%d , %d)\n'
                'stop codon %s\n'
                'nucleotide length %d\n'
                'amino acid length %d\n'
                'reading frame %d\n'
                %
                (match.start(1),match.end(1),
                 sequence[match.end(1)-3:match.end(1)],
                 match.end(1) - match.start(1),
                 (match.end(1) - match.start(1) - 3)/3,
                 match.start() % 3))

     return rframe

s = ('AGCTGCTG',
     'ATG',
     'GGG' 'GGG' 'GGG' 'GGG' 'GGG' 'GGG',
     'TA',
     'A', # overlaping
     'TG',
     'CCC' 'CCC' 'CCC' 'CCC' 'CCC',
     'TAG',
     'TTTGTCTAG')

print '\n'.join(s)
print '==================='
s = ''.join(s)
print '\n'.join(orfs(s,3))
```

result

```
AGCTGCTG
ATG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TA
A
TG
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
TAG
TTTGTCTAG
===================
groups() ('ATGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTAA',) (8, 8)
group(0) '' (8, 8)
group(1) 'ATGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTAA' (8, 32)

groups() ('ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG',) (31, 31)
group(0) '' (31, 31)
group(1) 'ATGCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCTAG' (31, 52)

span (8 , 32)
stop codon TAA
nucleotide length 24
amino acid length 7
reading frame 2

span (31 , 52)
stop codon TAG
nucleotide length 21
amino acid length 6
reading frame 1
```

Comment: I wrote the output like that in order to directly print it staggered on successive lines. If you want your output, nothing more easy than to add some ``1`` characters at the right places in your code, isn't it ?

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that this only returns the longest sequences? e.g. ATGATGAAATAA should only return that entire sequences, and shouldn't return ATGAAATAA.

Comment: By "longest sequence", do you mean sequences with as much as possible repetitions of ATG in front ? That is to say a new condition.

Comment: I mean to say that ATG is a 'start' codon only if it comes first. If there is another ATG preceding it in the same reading frame, it is simply just another amino acid, and shouldnt' be considered a new reading frame.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I would understand it if it was: ``I mean to say that ATG is a 'start' codon only if it comes first. If there is another ATG`` **FOLLOWING** ``it in the same reading frame, it is simply just another amino acid``

Comment: As the regex pattern has been written, by you by the way, it means that a repetition of one triplet must follow ``ATG`` and as this repeated triplet must only be one of ``AAA`` , ``TTT``, ``CCC`` , ``GGG`` , before an ending limit consisting in ``(?=TAG|TAA|TGA)``, the consequence is that there can't be any ``ATG`` following the said "first". Your question has no sense